# Как получить путь к файлу зная его Uri, но не зная его тип

Tags: java, android, uri, android-file

Мне нужно получить путь к файлу через его `Uri`. Ниже я привер пример как я это делаю для аудио файлов. Аналогичный код можно написать и для изображений, заменив `MediaStore.Audio` на `MediaStore.Images`.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static String getFilePath(Context context, Uri fileUri) {
    String filePath = null;
    String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(fileUri);

    // Split at colon, use second item in the array
    String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

    String[] column = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};

    // where id is equal to
    String sel = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + "=?";

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            column, sel, new String[]{id}, null);

    if (cursor==null)return null;

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return filePath;
}
```

Это будет работать если я зарение знаю что данный `Uri` относится к аудио файлу или к изображению.

**Вопрос:** как быть если я зарение не знаю какого типа этот файл?

Comment: Может попробовать узнать тип: `String mime = context.getContentResolver().getType(uri);` и от него плясать дальше...